# Selenium selecting value from dropdown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to select an option from this dropdown like this with Selenium

[CSS picture](https://gyazo.com/0d40bbb99c381393dbfe483e8da30ed2)

My problem is about to select one of the options, basically I cannot do it by className because all options have the same className... the only different between them is data_value and span value

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov I did it and it gave me this error  `no such element: Unable to locate element`

Comment: Is this element visible? First you have to click on dropdown button, then on the option

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov error is self explainatory + you got the idea now how to do it. You should work your way out now

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov I did it already '        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.className("js-open-tallas"));
        dropdown.click();' but when I tried to select the option it doesn't work and gave me that error I've been looking on the internet the whole day...

Comment: data-value was wrong, try this one `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-value='your value']"))` or this one `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-value='your value'] span"))`

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Thanks you're right, thanks a lot! you can add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select an option from dropdown you can use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-value='yourValue']"))
```

or this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-value='yourValue'] span"))
```